# elasticsearch using bulk insert to post JSON file

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following [JSON file](http://pastebin.com/raw/r2pdcaW8)

I have used awk to get rid of empty spaces, trailing, next line

```
awk -v ORS= -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1' data.json
```

I have added a create request at the top of my data.json followed by \n and the rest of my data.

```
{"create": {"_index":"socteam", "_type":"products"}}
```

When I issue bulk submit request, I get the following error

```
CURL -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_bulk

{
  "took": 1,
  "errors": true,
  "items": [
    {
      "create": {
        "_index": "socteam",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "AVQuGPff-1Y7OIPIJaLX",
        "status": 400,
        "error": {
          "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason": "failed to parse",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "not_x_content_exception",
            "reason": "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

Any idea on what this error mean? I haven't created any mapping, I'm using vanilla elasticsearch

Here is a payload Sample

```
cat data.json | awk -v ORS= -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1' | awk -v idx=test -v type=data 'BEGIN{print "{\"create\": {\"_index\":\"" idx "\", \"_type\":\"" type"\"}}"}; {print}; END {printf "\n"}' >> $file
        exit 0
        fi
    fi
```

Then I used httpie to submit the file to es

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data? Just two lines from the bulk API body would be fine (one index line and one data line)

Comment: I have attached sample JSON file to the question, it has sample data, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm not seeing any samples in the question. I'm seeing `CURL -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_bulk`, which has no data (just the response), and I see your index line, and I see an `awk` command, but no complete request. i.e. what is your actual document you are trying to index?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw/r2pdcaW8

Comment: That's not quite what I'm talking about. I mean your actual payload to the bulk API. You should have two lines for every document - the index line and the document line. Do you have the _actual payload_ you are sending?